# What's the fastest way to search for duplicates in an array without sorting it?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have an array 1 2 2 3 4. I wish to find the number of duplicates of an element after its index only. So the number of duplicates of first 2 is 1 and the number of duplicates of second 2 is 0. How can I achieve this?

Comment: A lookup table if the domain is sufficiently small.

Comment: Your description is not very clear to me, e.g. what's the number of duplicates of "3" in your example? And if there were a "3" in the 1st position, what would be its number of duplicates?

Comment: The best solution is really based on your context. For example maybe the best solution is to sort items as they're inserted. Or search for duplicates as items are added...

Comment: is the array fixed? if not, what's the insert/duplicatesearch ratio?

Answer (score 3):

Put elements that you see into a hash-based map.

Starting from the back of your collection, go backward, and add items to the hash map. If an element you are about to add is not there, set its duplicate count to zero, and put `1` into the map for that element. If a count is already there, then its duplicate count is whatever is in the map. Store that number as the duplicate count, and increment the value in the map.

```
vector<int> data({1, 2, 2, 3, 4});
unordered_map<int,int> count;
vector<int> res(data.size(), 0);
for (int i = data.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    res[i] = count[data[i]]++;
}
for (int i = 0 ; i != res.size() ; i++) {
    cout << data[i] << " - " << res[i] << endl;
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/McWRrM)

Comment: This does not take into account the element position as required.

Comment: @iavr I modified the answer to account for it - the biggest change is that you need to go backward. Thanks!

Comment: Going backwards is indeed a very clever idea :)

Comment: Again, this would be fine if we were looking for duplicates of an element after its first occurrence. But we're looking for duplicates of an element after *its index*. Which unfortunately is not very clear, see my comment under the question.

Comment: @iavr I am nearly sure that the OP meant the first occurrence, because he says that "number of duplicates of first 2 is 1". The first 2 is located at index 1, so he counted all 2s after index 1.

Answer (score 0):

If n is the size of the array and i is an index of an element then you need for each element to scan **n - i - 1** elements. As the result you will do **n * ( n - 1 )** comparisons of elements.

You can use standard algorithm `std::count`

For example

```
const size_t N = 5;

int a[N] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 };

for ( int *first = a; first != a + N; ++first )
{
   std::cout << *first << '\t' << std::count( first, a + N, *first ) - 1 << std::endl;
}
```

Or

```
for ( int *first = a; first != a + N; ++first )
{
   std::cout << *first << '\t' << std::count( first + 1, a + N, *first ) << std::endl;
}
```

The same can be written also as

```
for ( auto *first = std::begin( a ); first != std::end( a ); ++first )
{
   std::cout << *first << '\t' << std::count( first, std::end( a ), *first ) - 1 << std::endl;
}
```

or as

```
for ( auto *first = std::begin( a ); first != std::end( a ); ++first )
{
   std::cout << *first << '\t' << std::count( std::next( first ), std::end( a ), *first ) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  In this context it is a method.:)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I have not understood what you wanted to say.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Oh, I have seen the typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would be the fastest approach, but my offer would be to:

- Make a secondary array with same number of elements, initialize them with `0`s
- Check duplicates of the last element;

  - Mark the second from last duplicate with `1`,
  - then the third from last with `2`
  - and so on...
- Check duplicates of the elements from the last to the first, skip if the element has duplicate mark other than `0`

Like this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Length 10

int main( ) {

    int SomeNumbers[Length] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 9, 2, 3 };
    int DupCount[Length] = { 0 };

    for ( int i = Length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        if ( DupCount[i] == 0 ) {
            int dup = 0;
            for ( int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j-- )
                if ( SomeNumbers[i] == SomeNumbers[j] )
                    DupCount[j] = ++dup;
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < Length; i++ ) printf( "%d ", DupCount[i] );

    getchar( );
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient approach in terms of speed would typically be to use a frequency table. Normally, it is a structure which maps a value to the number of times it occurs. In this case, you could map to a list/array of indices instead (i.e. the index of each places where the value occurred).

The algorithm would go through each element, and add it to the table. If a duplicate is found, it gets appended the list/array of indices at that location in the map.

If you need to know how many duplicates there are e.g. of the number 2, then lookup its entry in the table. The number of indices stored there is the total number of duplicates. To find the number of duplicates after a given instance of the value, simply check how many indices occur *after* the desired index.